# clang recursive type derivation error for template members

Tags: templates, c++11, recursion, instantiation, clang++

This code is normally compiled with `gcc 4.8` and higher, but not by `clang++ 3.5` and higher. Instead [I have an error](http://goo.gl/V5kAu8):

`!!error: no viable conversion from 'Data<Data<double, double>, Data<double, double>>' to 'Data<double, double>'`

It means that  only instance for `func(Data<double,double>)` was generated.

Why nested structures  ignored?

Is this a bug in Clang? Or gcc go away from Standard?

```
template<class T1,class T2>
struct Data{
    T1 t1;    T2 t2;
    Data(T1 t1,T2 t2):t1(t1),t2(t2){}
};
template<class T1,class T2>
Data<T1,T2> make_Data(T1 t1,T2 t2){return Data<T1,T2>(t1,t2);}

struct Foo{
    template<class T> static
    double func(const T& t){return 0.1*t;}

    template<class T1,class T2>static
    auto func(const Data<T1,T2>& d)
      ->decltype(make_Data(func(d.t1),func(d.t2)))
    {return make_Data(func(d.t1),func(d.t2));}
};
template<class T>
auto apply_func(const T& t) 
  ->decltype(Foo::func(t))
{return Foo::func(t);}


int main() {
auto data=make_Data(make_Data(1,2),make_Data(3,4));
auto data1=apply_func(data);

return 0;
}
```

As a [workaround](http://goo.gl/LW4jP7) I have to make my `struct Foo` template

```
template<class T>
struct Foo{        
    static double func(const T& t){return 0.1*t;}
};
template<class T>
auto apply_func(const  T& t)
  ->decltype(Foo<T>::func(t))
{return Foo<T>::func(t);}

template<class T1,class T2>
struct Foo<Data<T1,T2>>{
static auto func(const Data<T1,T2>& d)
      ->decltype(make_Data(apply_func(d.t1),apply_func(d.t2)))
    {return make_Data(apply_func(d.t1),apply_func(d.t2));}

};
```

but is whis case  function `apply_func` should  be used in implementation and declared before class specialization.